# Saving multiple foreach value

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently getting the same $val results but the $key is working fine. What am i doing wrong?

```
            foreach($awards['award_title'] as $key) {
                foreach($_POST['award_title_new'] as $val) 
                $award_title_trans[$key] = $val;
            }
            update_option('award_title',  $award_title_trans );
```

$awards array:

```
              ["award_title"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(7) "testnew"
                [1]=>
                string(5) "newti"
              }
```

and the $POST is an input array name='award_title_new[]'

What i am expecting is to save the $awards value as a key and the $POST as the value:

```
            array(2) {
              ["testnew"]=>
              string(3) "345"
              ["newti"]=>
              string(3) "345"
            }
```

Comment: What do the 2 arrays look like? What are you expecting as a result? Have a look at this [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AnilAstrio, Update your question, Also add expected result too.

Comment: and what are you expecting as a result?

Comment: Ok, **no cigar yet**, what is in the `award_title_new` array

Comment: @RiggsFolly the array to capture the foreach. Maybe i am doing this wrong as i am a novice but using this method works fine for all my other codes. $award_title_trans[$key] = $val;

Comment: @RiggsFolly I found the answer. $array_merge_new = array_combine($awards['award_title'], $_POST['award_title_new']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick!

> array_combine($awards['award_title'], $_POST['award_title_new']);

```
            array(2) {
              ["testnew"]=>
              string(3) "hello"
              ["newti"]=>
              string(3) "bye"
            }
```